# SharePoint Licesnse How Microsoft calculate it?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, licensing

I have some questions related to SharePoint License , I hope to find a trusted answer about that.

- How Microsoft calculate the SharePoint license as per server license and as per CAL license , What's the difference  ?
- How Many times can I use the SharePoint key ?
- What's the period of key expiration ?
- Can I use the same SharePoint key for multiple servers?
- What about the effect of using a real SharePoint key for personal use , is this will effect on the key owner?
- Can Microsoft know who use a specific key by listing the servers IP list and its location ?
- Is Microsoft inform the key owner that someone has been used your key ?
- Is there a free key for personal / dev environment ?
- Is there any walkthrough to extend SharePoint 2013 Trail for a personal environment without reinstall farm ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Each SharePoint Server must be licensed (with a Standard or Enterprise license).
- Each user must be licensed with a SharePoint User CAL. For Standard only features, they just need a SharePoint Standard User CAL. For Enterprise features, you must assign them a SharePoint Standard *and* Enterprise User CAL.
- You can use the key as many times as you want, but of course you must license each server the key is used with.
- The key does not expire.
- You can use the same key as many times as you need to.
- Keys are licensed to a specific organization. "Personal" use would likely fall out of scope of what the key is licensed for, unless you purchased your own copy of SharePoint Server.
- The key is not tracked by any means.
- There are no free keys for personal/development use -- instead, get an MSDN Subscription or provision the SharePoint Farm option on Azure (which you pay for the running costs of the VM, but not Windows or SharePoint).
- You cannot extend the trial of a SharePoint farm.

Comment: I need to install SharePoint on 4 servers. How many keys will I need? 4 or 1?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a Virtual Machine with Windows Server running, and reinstall your SharePoint Farm every time the trial expires.
It's a bit annoying but it works for developing solutions without hardcoded GUIDs (because when you reinstall your farm the GUID identifiers will change for all the lists and views)
In a corporate infrastructure, it is common to have several environments (DEV, QA, PROD) and as far as I know, licenses are only taken into account for the production (PROD) environment.

Comment: That depends.  Anything not falling under the specific terms of an MSDN license (assuming you're licensed for MSDN) will require a valid SharePoint license for each server, regardless of the environment's name.

Comment: thank you for the clarification, by te way we have a golden partner MSDN subscription.